# How to find if a frequency table key column contains all values from a list

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data

I have a data frame, and I am doing a frequency table count for a column. I want to search if the `key` column in the table contains all values in this list `ls = ['Agree', 'Disagree', 'Neutral', 'N/A']`, if the column `key` misses some values in the list, I want to add the missing values to the column and make their `count` as 0. Is that something that can be executed when calculating the frequency table?

For example, I have already calculated my frequency table using `value_counts` here and transform it into data frame.

```
# df
key        count
Agree       22
Disagree    30
Neutral     12
```

Expected output

```
key        count
Agree       22
Disagree    30
Neutral     12
N/A          0
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert first values of `key` column to Categoricals, so if missing key by default are added new row with `0` count after [`Series.values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.values.html):

```
ls = ['Agree', 'Disagree', 'Neutral', 'N/A'] 

df['key'] = pd.Categorical(df['key'], categories=ls)
#if need order like values in list
#df['key'] = pd.Categorical(df['key'], categories=ls, ordered=True)

df1 = df['key'].value_counts().rename_axis('key').reset_index(name='count')
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But could you explain a bit on `rename_axis('key').reset_index(name='count')`? How did they happen to name the columns by the order `['key', 'count']`? I know  `rename_axis` rename the index prior `reset_index`. But also `reset_index(name='count')` give the index name? So there are two index names (in the first column), but it's not the case when I run the code. Thanks!

Comment: @Lumos - `.rename_axis('key')` create index name, it is necessary for column called `key` after `reset_index` and also `reset_index(name='count')` working for Series - it create dataframe with column name `count`

Answer (score 0):

You can `reindex` the resulting `Series` using the list:

```
ls = ['Agree', 'Disagree', 'Neutral', 'N/A']
df['key'].value_counts().reindex(ls, fill_value=0)
```